# Trying to e.164 a phone number from form input

Tags: python, python-phonenumber

I'm trying to take a UK mobile phone number input from a web form and use Python to clean it into a E.164 format, then validate it, before entering it into a database.

The library I'm trying to use is "Phonenumbers" and the code I'm experimenting with so far is:

```
def Phone():
    my_number = '+4407808765066'
    clean_phone = phonenumbers.parse(my_number, "GB")
    cleaner_phone = phonenumbers.format_number(clean_phone, 
    phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
    valid = phonenumbers.is_possible_number(cleaner_phone)
    print(cleaner_phone)
```

Just working through the logic, my expectation is that it should take the contents of `my_number` variable, format it through into the `clean_phone` variable, then format it to E.164 standard before passing it to the validation and return the output to `valid`. The print statement is for me to see the output.

Everything looks to work ok if I comment out the `valid` variable line. As soon as I uncomment it, I get an error (see below).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phone_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    Phone()
  File "phone_test.py", line 10, in Phone
    valid = phonenumbers.is_possible_number(cleaner_phone)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner_driver_app\env\lib\site-packages\phonenumbers\phonenumberutil.py", line 2257, in is_possible_number      
    result = is_possible_number_with_reason(numobj)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner_driver_app\env\lib\site-packages\phonenumbers\phonenumberutil.py", line 2358, in is_possible_number_with_reason
    return is_possible_number_for_type_with_reason(numobj, PhoneNumberType.UNKNOWN)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner_driver_app\env\lib\site-packages\phonenumbers\phonenumberutil.py", line 2393, in is_possible_number_for_type_with_reason
    national_number = national_significant_number(numobj)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner_driver_app\env\lib\site-packages\phonenumbers\phonenumberutil.py", line 1628, in national_significant_number
    if numobj.italian_leading_zero:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'italian_leading_zero'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the phone number stored in my_number is a a valid number?

Comment: it should be, it's the standard international format for a Uk mobile......as far as i'm aware :)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#Format) phone numbers in the UK go up to 10 digits in length and can be preceded by a two digit country code. Your number, "44 0780 876506 6" appears to have an extra digit. (not from the UK or a phone number expert, just speculating)

Comment: @0x263A - The number is definitely UK valid mobile. I'm sure the code strips the +44 and  0 first, then it re-adds the +44 back to make it an E.164 format number. So that bit works fine as of testing it last night. What I then realised, is that the final part "is_valid_number" is actually a boolean. I think that's why it's throwing the string error. I'd still like to use the "validity" check but I don't know how to get from the previous output to a boolean output?

Answer (score 5):

Your `my_number` is a variable of type `str` (string), thus the last line of your error). The string class does not know the attribute `national_number`.
Reading through their examples on GitHub, I suspect you need to pass your string through the `parse()` function first before you can use functions from the library.

```py
def phone_parser():
    my_number = '+4407811111111'
    number_parsed = phonenumbers.parse(my_number, None)  # this is new
    clean_phone = phonenumbers.format_number(number_parsed, 
    phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
    return clean_phone
```

The `None` in `parse()` may be replaced by a country code if it is known. Otherwise, it will try to figure it out but may fail.

Edit to account for more information in the original question:
Apparently `phonenumbers.format_number()` returns a string, therefore you have to re-parse the number again to get an object of type `phonenumbers.phonenumber.PhoneNumber` (you can check the type of objects with `type(my_object)`). After that, your code will return `True`.

Comment: Yea looking back at my code, I think I posted the wrong version of it, my bad. I've updated my question. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I edited my answer so it hopefully covers your question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `format_number` function with a string as argument, it expects a `PhoneNumber` object.

You can get one by using the `parse` function.

See https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/tree/dev/python#example-usage

Comment: Yes thanks @mrkrieger1. I managed to rework the code and get it doing what I need. Thanks :)